# Технологии онлайн игр

Tags: веб-программирование, разработка-игр

Если начинать делать большую по функциональности, но маленькую по графике игру, какие технологии выбрать?

Comment: Сначала нужно определиться какая это будет игра, браузерная или клиент-серверная. И от этого уже отталкиваться, т.к. технологии там совершенно разные.

Comment: Я бы даже сказал надо сначала подумать чего вы хотите от игры. Технологий много, а что необходимо вам уже надо смотреть из тех запросов что вы составите при планировании.

Comment: Мне нужен интересный сюжет, много игроков и красивая графика. Это серверная игра.

Comment: Как вариант opengl mysql. Первый графика, второе - СУБД т.к. раз много народу надо где-то всю информацию хранить.

Comment: Я as3 и php и mysql будет лучше чем openGL + субд?

Comment: Это если браузерная, а тут автор уже сказал что серверная.
Но даже для веба я бы не as3 взял а яву с WebGL. Флеш дыряв как решето и бывает вешает браузер.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Классика для социальных игрушек:
клиент flash - сервер php + mysql.

Более продвинутый вариант с 3д графикой и модными технологиями (для социальных игрушек):
клиент unity - сервер python + mongodb.

Клиент серверная игра а-ля WOW
клиент с++ - сервер java/c# + mysql/postgresql

Браузерка 
js + php + mysql

В каждом пункте возможны бесчисленные вариации. По большому счёту для севера технологии не имеют решающего значения, а для клиента они однозначно диктуются требованиями к платформе и качеству графики.

Comment: В 3D мне не надо, а вот вариант flash + php + mysql это для меня как раз.

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант: php + js + mysql + талантливый pixelart художник. А сюжетом пусть займутся сами игроки; главное - периодически делать добавления/изменения игрового процесса. Отличный пример такого подхода: Warchaos. Однако на большую аудиторию рассчитывать не придется, не все поймут такую игру.

Comment: у меня друг днями и ночами пилит плагины для вархаоса :-D